# Package "jaccard" not installing properly

Tags: r, package, install.packages, q-value

here is the code I am using:

```
install.packages("jaccard")
library("jaccard")
```

The error code I receive is:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘jaccard’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘qvalue’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘jaccard’ was built under R version 3.6.3
```

I try to install the package qvalue and receive the error:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘qvalue’ is not available (for R version 3.6.2)
```

I've also tried installing jaccard and qvalue using the code:

```
install.packages("jaccard", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/", dependencies=TRUE)
install.packages("qvalue", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/", dependencies=TRUE)
```

None of this seems to work and I receive the same errors.

Comment: looks like you will need to install `qvalue` from https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/qvalue.html

Comment: @user20650 That worked, thank you so much!